# How to view Specific Category to Specific user id on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add category for Specific user. Later at front-end user will see only selected category posts. is it possible?

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible.
first of all, you have to save post category ids in user meta from the backend. for saving category id you can use the ACF plugin.

in the frontend, you have to get category ids from the logged-in user meta and add a condition based on it.

Answer (score 0):

i made my own functions.php its working perfectly..

Here my codes:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'crf_show_extra_profile_fields',10, 1 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'crf_show_extra_profile_fields',10, 1);

function crf_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) {
    $user_cat_id = get_the_author_meta( '_user_cat', $user->ID );
    ?>
    <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'Personal Category', 'crf' ); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="cat"><?php esc_html_e( 'User Category', 'crf' ); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <?php 
                
                 $args = array(
                    'show_option_none'   => 'User Category',
                    'option_none_value'  => '',
                    'selected'  => $user_cat_id,
                    
                );
                wp_dropdown_categories($args);
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', 'crf_user_profile_update_errors', 10, 3 );
function crf_user_profile_update_errors( $errors, $update, $user ) {
    if ( ! $update ) {
        return;
    }
}


add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'crf_update_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'crf_update_profile_fields' );

function crf_update_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['cat'] )) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, '_user_cat', intval( $_POST['cat'] ) );
    }
}
```

For to use at front-end use this code

$usercatid = get_the_author_meta( '_user_cat', $current_user->ID );